# How to marshal wchar[]

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I've found plenty of information about how to marshal `wchar_t` and `wchar*` on the internet, but right now I am trying to marshal the `WINBIO_STRING` type, which is defined as `wchar[256]`. Marshalling it as an array of `char[]` works, but then every other element in the array is `\0`, and I would like to avoid this. Is there a more proper way to marshal this data (which is a member of a struct, the `WINBIO_UNIT_SCHEMA` struct in particular). This is my code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct BiometricUnitSchema
{
    public int UnitId;
    public BiometricPoolType PoolType;
    public BiometricType BiometricFactor;
    public BiometricSubtype SensorSubType;
    public BiometricCapabilities Capabilities;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
    public char[] DeviceInstanceId;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
    public char[] Description;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
    public char[] Manufacturer;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
    public char[] Model;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
    public char[] SerialNumber;
    public BiometricVersion FirmwareVersion;
}
```

I also have the problem of the FirmwareVersion field always containing MajorVersion and MinorVersion values of 0, but I am not sure if this result is incorrect or simply misleading.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by marshaling WINBIO_STRING as a string in C# instead of a char[]. I also had to add a Unicode charset to my structure.

My new structure:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct BiometricUnitSchema
{
    public int UnitId;
    public BiometricPoolType PoolType;
    public BiometricType BiometricFactor;
    public BiometricSubtype SensorSubType;
    public BiometricCapabilities Capabilities;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public string DeviceInstanceId;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public string Description;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public string Manufacturer;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public string Model;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public string SerialNumber;
    public BiometricVersion FirmwareVersion;
}
```